# How can we play device default notification sound when the app is active in ionic-cordova?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I wanted to play the device default notification sound(Which user has set) when the app in active in ionic framework.

I tried ionic-ringtones but this gives the list of ringtones available in the device. But my requirement is to find and play the default ringtone or default message tone.

Comment: any solution you get for this?